# Python interface and self instanciation

Tags: python, inheritance, design-patterns, interface

I have a question of a more design nature regarding a simple strategy design pattern.

Lets say I have an interface:

```
class RenewInterface:
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        self.var1 = {}
        self.var2 = []
        if args:
            for i in args:
                inst = i()
                self.var1[inst.__class__.__name__] = inst

    @abstractmethod
    def renew(*args, **kwargs)
        Do some stuff and call renew in self.var1[inst__class__.__name__]

class ChildClass(RenewInterface):
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        super(ChildClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def renew(self, *args, **kwargs)
        Do more stuff
```

When I inherit from that class and if I choose to call the superclass `__init__` (the above code). If I have no args then I will only expose the `var1` and `var2` to the child class, but if I for some reason had args and I called the parent(RenewInterface) with `super(ChildClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` and the arg for some reason was the class of ChildClass, then I guess I would instantiate the ChildClass from itself? Since I don't care about the variables in the superclass is OK to:

1. Skip calling the superclass
2. Skip the `__init__` all together in the ChildClass?, but then it uses the RenewInterface `__init__` again for instantiation

I've tried it all and it all works, but I'm not sure what the most "pythonic" way of doing it is? Or more importantly, does this vary from version 2.6, 2.7 and python>=3.3.

I've read the docs and tried to google, but I have not found any conclusive information :(

Regards

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, so I'll just answer the small questions in your question: 1) _"if the arg was string class of self, would I instanciate the ChildClass from itself?"_ What on earth is "string class of self" supposed to mean? And no, that wouldn't instantiate anything. Your class would end up _calling_ a string - that'd be an error. 2) _"Since I don't care about the variables in the superclass, is OK to:"_ No, it's not ok. If you don't care about the variables of the parent class, then you shouldn't inherit from the parent class to begin with.

Comment: Had a typo in the there, if arg was a class ChildClass, no string what so ever. The code above is more sudo code, and is a minimal representation of the working code. Even if I don't care about the variables a certainly do care about the methods this they make up the basic of the strategy pattern (as I see it, that is)

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong.

It seems what you want to know the most pythonic way to handle method overloading, specifically, the **init** method to solve your problem.

The options are:
 1. Overload method, but don't call the super class' method
 2. Do not overload the method. Leave the super class' method to be called.

This is not a 'pythonic' issue, it rather has to do with OO.
The base class methods provide a default implementation. If you do not want the default implementation, then override the method. From what I hear, you are not happy with the default implementation for your child class. Override it.